# HTML --> PDF with PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

How can I convert an HTML page (via `$cURL` or something) to a PDF file?

Comment: [please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php) [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403820/html-to-pdf-not-pdf-to-html-in-php) [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560776/using-php-to-create-a-pdf-from-a-mix-of-plain-text-and-html-text) [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733219/converting-html-to-pdf-using-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

There are many scripts that do this, some of them:

[HTML_ToPDF 3.5](http://www.rustyparts.com/pdf.php)

> HTML_ToPDF is a PHP class that makes
>   it easy to convert HTML documents to
>   PDF files on the fly. HTML_ToPDF grew
>   out of the need to convert HTML files
>   (which are easy to create) to PDF
>   files (which are not so easy to
>   create) fast and easily.

[HTML 2 PDF - a PHP script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf/)

> Get a HTML text and generate a PDF
>   file to make it printer-friendly. This
>   PHP script is based upon FPDF PHP
>   script (www.fpdf.org). More info can
>   be found on the home page
>   (http://html2fpdf.sourceforge.net/).

[dompdf](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf)

> Handy for PHP developers looking to
>   generate PDFs from their HTML content:
>   dompdf is an HTML to PDF converter
>   written entirely in PHP5. It has no
>   dependencies on external libraries
>   (e.g. html2ps) and it supports CSS
>   2.1.

Answer (score 2):

Try: "[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)" it just work great (and its -open source-). It uses **webkit** engine (used by safari, chrome browsers) and it is very easy to use :

```
wkhtmltopdf stackoverflow.com/questions/1702834/ output.pdf
```

Try it! for Linux and Windows as well. Easy to install. If you use ubuntu, type:

```
aptitude install wkhtmltopdf
```

Then in your PHP just use the exec() command.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) ?

Comment: It has many issues with rendering images and tables that have many rows.