# Opening HTML page, then saving it to PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf

I need to open an .html file first and display that info on the web browser.  Then once it is open have it save that .html page to a pdf on my server.

Comment: Ok. What's your question, what's the result of your Google search and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something free and/or simple? Oracle's UCM — well, Inbound Refinery — can do the conversion of HTML to PDF, but it's a serious, industrial-strength solution.

EDIT:
I see you've got the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag going. You may find these three questions relevant:

- [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)
- [html to pdf (not pdf to html) in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403820/html-to-pdf-not-pdf-to-html-in-php)
- [HTML > PDF with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702834/html-pdf-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to kick off a simple python script to do the job, [PyODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter) can convert from HTML (among many other formats) to PDF and vice versa. It is a wrapper to the underlying [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) java library (which can also be run from the CLI)

Answer (score 0):

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) might be useful for something like this. It's a simple command line tool.